# odata query - is there a way to add an "and false" to a filter

Tags: odata

odata query - is there a way to add an "and false" to a filter

This is a query connected to a SAP system.

Lets say my url is:

/PlannerGrpSet?$top=50&$filter=(Werks eq '3000')&$select=*

And I want to do:

/PlannerGrpSet?$top=50&$filter=(Werks eq '3000' and false )&$select=*

Don't ask me why, we have a tool that is translating some complex sql that we generate and in sql we do 0=1 to signify to not return data.  Yes, I know we are insane.

Just adding **and false** gives:

The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error

Any ideas on how I get what I want?  Again, not looking for "don't do that".  Also I'd rather not rely on trying to do something like Werks eq '3000' and Werks eq '3001', ideally I wouldn't want to have to pick one of our columns at random and do something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [grammar](http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.0/errata02/os/complete/abnf/odata-abnf-construction-rules.txt) for `$filter` expressions does allow for a primitive literal (e.g., `false`) on the right-hand side of an `and` expression. So it looks like you are bumping up against a bug or limitation of the OData implementation behind your service.

Here's a working [example from the TripPin demo service](http://services.odata.org/V4/(S(ztoosdlp5wrqdiv233gmrqys))/TripPinServiceRW/People?$filter=UserName%20eq%20%27russellwhyte%27%20and%20false) with a literal `false` value in the `$filter`.

```
http://services.odata.org/V4/(S(ztoosdlp5wrqdiv233gmrqys))/TripPinServiceRW/People?$filter=UserName eq 'russellwhyte' and false
```

You could try a different logical expression that is guaranteed to fail. E.g., `0 eq 1`.

Comment: I think you are correct that it is a limitation of the SAP backend.  Do you know if version 2.0 of oData also supports primitive literals?  Is there a demo service for version 2?  Sorry for the extra questions.  I did try 0 eq 1 but also hit errors.

Comment: According to http://download.microsoft.com/download/9/5/E/95EF66AF-9026-4BB0-A41D-A4F81802D92C/[MS-ODATA].pdf (version 2 spec), Section 2.2.3.6.1.1 Common Expression Syntax, a boolean literal is legal in `$filter`. But the`boolLiteralExpression` rule is defined with this caveat: "A data service MAY support expressions that are literals representing a
Boolean value." That means it's optional.

Comment: Hit a very similar issue in Azurite, the Azure Storage emulator. I wanted a query that will return nothing, as part of a check that the table being queried exists. Literal `false` as `$filter` produced a 400 response, same as `0 eq 1`. `PartitionKey eq null` worked in Azurite, but not in actual Azure Storage. Ultimately, I used `PartitionKey eq 'NONEXISTENT'`.